# PyQt running screen 2 times (stackedWidget)

Tags: python, pyqt, qstackedwidget

I'm developing a simple application using PyQt. Basically, when a I press the button "Go Back to Screen 1" on `screen 2` my application goes to `screen 1`. However, it executes the method of `screen 2` two times.

The best way to understand the problem is:

1. When the application starts click on button `Screen 2`
2. Click the button `Go Back To Screen 1`
3. Press `ok`
4. Click on the button `Screen 2` again
5. Click the button `Go Back To Screen 1`
6. Press `ok`

Doing this process, the pop will show 2 times on screen 1 (the method `test` is called 3 times instead 2)

Why is this happening since I clicked only two times on the Button `Screen 2`? I've debugged the code and didn't find a way to fix this. The MVCE:

main.py:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

from Ui_MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_win = QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.main_win)

        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.page)

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.showScreen1)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.showScreen2)

    def show(self):
        self.main_win.show()

    def test(self):
        print("Just a test")
        self.showPopUp()
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.page)

    def showPopUp(self):
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        msg.setText("A window")
        msg.setInformativeText("A window")
        msg.setWindowTitle("AVISO")
        msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)
        retval = msg.exec_()


    def showScreen1(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.page)

    def showScreen2(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.page_2)
        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.test)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_win = MainWindow()
    main_win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Ui_MainWindow.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(485, 239)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 451, 171))
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 80, 91, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_2)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 30, 91, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.page_2)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 130, 121, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 200, 221, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 200, 221, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SCREEN 1"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SCREEN 2"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Go back to Screen 1"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SCREEN 1"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SCREEN 2"))
```

Comment: move `self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.test)` after `self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.showScreen2)`

Comment: @eyllanesc all signals must go on `__init__`?

Comment: All the signals must be done once, in your case more connections are being added each time the showScreen2 function is invoked. The signals do not identify if they have already connected to the same function.